# What is the default ubuntu 12.10 firewall?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, proxy, firewall

I have been trying to get ubuntu one to work (i.e. sync my files), but it keeps saying that it is "getting information" and "please wait". I only have 338MB used on my Ubuntu, so it shouldn't take that long, should it? I read that this was due to a firewall issue. I can't seem to locate the place at which I would change the settings. Where would I go? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. But is off topic. A support request should be opened, or a bug filed, about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Standard, unless you've enabled it, is the firewall OFF in Ubuntu 12.10 (and other versions)

to enable the firewall type `sudo ufw enable` 
to check if it's working typ `sudo ufw status` 
to disable the firewall type `sudo ufw disable`

all in a terminal.

In the softwarecenter you can find GUFW a graphic frontend to control your firewall; 
you can make rules for the firewall, as you can easily enable/disable it with a slider.